# How can i create an enum in a vyper file

Tags: vyper

Is there a way to create an enum in a vyper file ?

I have tried this:

```
from enum import Enum
```

But it does not work

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like **Enums** were added to _Vyper_.  Details below.

Comment: Added this July in v0.3.4 :-) -> https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/releases/tag/v0.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enums** were added to *Vyper*.  Not sure when, but it's in `v0.3.7`.  Example:

```
# _Defining an enum with two members
enum Roles:
    ADMIN
    USER

# Declaring an enum variable
role: Roles = Roles.ADMIN

# Returning a member
return Roles.ADMIN
```

[Full details at *readthedocs*.](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#enums)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native enum type in Vyper, so you'll have to construct your own.

Others may have better ideas, but you could either use:

- A [fixed-size list](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#fixed-size-lists)
- A [mapping](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#mappings)

...but you'll have to consider the gas costs of each.

The best alternative is probably to architect your contract in such a way as to avoid needing enums.